# How to explode on varchar in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have a requirement where i need to explode a varchar to get data into multiple lines.

Sample data:

```
1, ab cd ef 

2, ee dd
```

Output expected:

```
1, ab

1, cd

1, ef

2, ee

2, dd
```

Please suggest how can we achieve this in hive.

Comment: The data type of second column in table is varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table mytable (id int,mycolumn string);

insert into mytable values
    (1,'ab cd ef')
   ,(2,'ee dd')
;
```

---

```
select      t.id
           ,e.val 

from        mytable t 
            lateral view explode(split(mycolumn,' ')) e as val
;
```

---

```
+------+-------+
| t.id | e.val |
+------+-------+
|    1 | ab    |
|    1 | cd    |
|    1 | ef    |
|    2 | ee    |
|    2 | dd    |
+------+-------+
```